# Submit button returns nothing, value associated with particular page does not increment PHP

Tags: php

Making a simple three question PHP quiz.  Each question is displayed on a page of its own, when the submit button is pressed, the variable $number should increment by one and its value determines the current page that is displayed on the user's browser.  It appears that somehow this variable is not incrementing correctly -- when the submit button is pressed, the page does not change.   I would really like to get this program running.  I would imagine this is a relatively simple script for most of you.  If someone could assist in getting this to run, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',900);
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== 1) {
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}

if(isset($_SESSION["correct"])){
$correct = $_SESSION["correct"];
} else {
$number = 0;
$correct = 0;
}

// check if which question was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// set $number = the question that was submitted
$number = $_POST['question'];
switch ($_POST['question']){
    case 1:
        if ($_POST['answer'] == 'false'){
          $correct++; // this answer should be 'false'
          break;
        }
    case 2:
        if ($_POST['answer'] == 2){
          $correct++;// this answer should be 'PA'
          break; 
        }
    case 3:
    if ($_POST['answer'] == "lee") {
          $correct++;//this answer should be 'lee'
          break;
          }
}
}   

// set the session correct var to our current tally
$_SESSION['correct'] = $correct;



$total_number = 3;

print <<<TOP
<html>
<head>
<title> History Quiz </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> History Quiz </h3>
TOP;

if ($number == 0){
print <<<FIRST
<p> You will be given $total_number questions in this quiz. <br /><br/>
  You will have 15 minutes to complete it. <br /><br/>
  You cannot go back to change previous answers.<br /><br/>
  Here is your first question: <br /><br />
</p>
<p>1. Abe Lincoln was born in Illinois.</p>
<p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="true" /> True </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="false" /> False </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="1" />
</p>
FIRST;
}


if ($number == 1){
print <<<SECOND
<p>2. In what state was the battle of Gettysburg fought?</p>
<p>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="1" /> a) Texas  
</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="2" /> b)  
Pennsylvania </label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="3" /> c) Virginia   
</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="4" /> d) West   
Virginia </label>
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="2" />
</p>
SECOND;
}
if ($number == 2){
print <<<THIRD
<p>3. The last name of the commander of the Army of North Virginia was __________.</p>
<p>
    <input type='text' id='answer' />
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="3" />
</p>
THIRD;
}

if ($number >= $total_number)
{
 print <<<FINAL_SCORE
Your final score is $correct correct out of $total_number. <br /><br />
Thank you for playing. <br /><br />
FINAL_SCORE;
session_destroy();
}
else {
$number++;
$_SESSION['number'] = $number;
$script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
print <<<FORM
<form method = "post" action = $script>
<input type = "submit" value = "Check Answer" />
</form>
FORM;
}


?>
```

UPDATE:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',900);
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== 1) {
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
}

if(isset($_SESSION["correct"]) and isset($_SESSION["number"])){
$correct = $_SESSION["correct"];
$number = $_SESSION["number"];
} else {
$number = 0;
$correct = 0;
}


// check if which question was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// set $number = the question that was submitted
$number = $_SESSION['number'];
switch ($_POST['question']){
    case 1:
        if ($_POST['answer1'] == 'false'){
          $correct++; // this answer should be 'false'
          break;
        }
    case 2:
        if ($_POST['answer2'] == "PA"){
          $correct++;// this answer should be 'PA'
          break; 
        }
    case 3:
    if ($_POST['answer3'] == "lee") {
          $correct++;//this answer should be 'lee'
          break;
          }
}
}   

// set the session correct var to our current tally
$_SESSION['correct'] = $correct;



$total_number = 3;

print <<<TOP
<html>
<head>
<title> History Quiz </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> History Quiz </h3>
TOP;
$script = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if ($number == 0){
print <<<FIRST
<p> You will be given $total_number questions in this quiz. <br /><br/>
  You will have 15 minutes to complete it. <br /><br/>
  You cannot go back to change previous answers.<br /><br/>
  Here is your first question: <br /><br />
</p>
<p>1. Abe Lincoln was born in Illinois.</p>
<p>
    <form method = "post" action = "$script">
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="true" /> True </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="answer1" value="false" /> False </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="1" />
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Check Answer" />
    </form>
</p>
FIRST;
}


if ($number == 1){
print <<<SECOND
<p>2. In what state was the battle of Gettysburg fought?</p>
<p>
<form method = "post" action = "$script">
<label><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="Texas" /> a) Texas  
</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="PA" /> b)  
Pennsylvania </label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="Vir" /> c) Virginia   
</label><br/>
<label><input type="radio" name="answer2" value="West" /> d) West   
Virginia </label>
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="2" />
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Check Answer" />
</form>
</p>
SECOND;
}
if ($number == 2){
print <<<THIRD
<p>3. The last name of the commander of the Army of North Virginia was __________.</p>
<p>
    <form method = "post" action = "$script">
    <input type='text' id='answer3' />
<input type="hidden" name="question" value="3" />
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Check Answer" />
    </form>
</p>
THIRD;
}

if ($number >= $total_number)
{
print <<<FINAL_SCORE
Your final score is $correct correct out of $total_number. <br /><br />
Thank you for playing. <br /><br />
FINAL_SCORE;
session_destroy();
}
else {
$number++;
$_SESSION['number'] = $number;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I just have to ask you why you're using HEREDOC. I've never seen someone do it that way.

Anyways, a few things I noticed:

1. All of your input fields are being printed above and outside of your form, not sure if that it intentional, but it appears that it is not. Only things inside the actual form will be submitted with that form. Your form needs to surround *all* of your input fields that you want sent with it *and* your submit button.
2. Your submit button **has no name**. You can't retrieve the value of the submit button unless you name it 'submit', for example. Thus `isset($_POST['submit'])` will always return false because there is no field with the name 'submit'.
3. Your `action = $script` statement should still include quotations around `$script` for HTML syntax reasons, otherwise you'll get something like `action=/path/to/file`.
4. What @MrTrick said should help you as well, although that won't kill your script.
5. For your answers, you are incorrectly using the checkbox type. You should be using the radio type so that only one option can be selected.

Comment: What a fantastic answer!!  Just fantastic!  I made these changes (in addition to MrTricks suggestion) and now everyone works except the fact that when I put in all the right answers, it says that I only have 2 out of 3 right.  Maybe the script doesn't get the value of one of the questions correctly?

Comment: @kmimage: Your third answer field `<input type='text' id='answer3' />` needs to have a name, not an ID. It's not being submitted because it has no name.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your program flow; If `$_SESSION['correct']` is set, then no value is ever assigned to `$number`.

Maybe it should be:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["correct"]) and isset($_SESSION["number"])){
    $correct = $_SESSION["correct"];
    $number = $_SESSION["number"];
} else {
    $number = 0;
    $correct = 0;
}
```

If you have PHP error logging set to `STRICT`, it should have reported a `Notice` error where you check the value of `$number` without having set it to anything.